# Persistent AWK Program

Tags: bash, awk, log4j

I have been tasked with writing a BASH script to filter log4j files and pipe them over netcat to another host. One of the requirements is that the script must keep track of what it has already sent to the server and not send it again due to licensing constraints on the receiving server (the product on the server is licensed on a data-per-day model).

To achieve the filtering I'm using AWK encapsulated in a BASH script. The BASH component works fine - it's the AWK program that's giving me grief when I try to get it to remember what has already been sent to the server. I am doing this by grabbing the time stamp of a line each time a line matches my pattern. At the end of the program the last time stamp is written to a hidden file in current working directory. On successive runs of the program AWK will read this file in to a variable. Now each time a line matches the pattern it's time stamp is also compared to the one in the variable. If it is newer it is printed, otherwise it is not.

Desired Output:

> INFO  2012-11-07 09:57:12,479 [[artifactid].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: MsgID=5017f1ff-1dfa-48c7-a03c-ed3c29050d12 InteractionStatus=Accept InteractionDateTime=2012-08-07T16:57:33.379+12:00 Retailer=CTCT RequestType=RemoteReconnect

Hidden File:

> 2012-10-11 12:08:19,918

So that's the theory, now my issue.

The script works fine for contrived/ trivial examples such as:

> INFO  2012-11-07 09:57:12,479 [[artifactid].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: MsgID=5017f1ff-1dfa-48c7-a03c-ed3c29050d12 InteractionStatus=Accept InteractionDateTime=2012-08-07T16:57:33.379+12:00 Retailer=CTCT RequestType=RemoteReconnect

However, if I run it over a full blown log file with stack traces etc in it then the indentation levels appear to wreck havoc on my program. The first run of the program will produce the desired results - matching lines will be printed and the latest time stamp written to the hidden file. Running it again is when the problem crops up. The output of the program contains the indented lines from stack traces etc (see the block below) and I can't figure out why. This then stuffs the hidden file as the last matching line doesn't contain a time stamp and some garbage is written to it making any further runs pointless.

Undesired output:

> at package.reverse.domain.SomeClass.someMethod(SomeClass.java:233)
>       at package.reverse.domain.processor.SomeClass.process(SomeClass.java:129)
>       at package.reverse.domain.processor.someClass.someMethod(SomeClassjava:233)
>       at package.reverse.domain.processor.SomeClass.process(SomeClass.java:129)

Hidden file after:

> package.reverse.domain.process(SomeClass.java:129)

My awk program:

```
FNR == 1 {
    CMD = "basename " FILENAME
    CMD | getline FILE;
    FILE = "." FILE ".last";
    if (system("[ -f "FILE" ]") == 0) {
        getline FIRSTLINE < FILE;
        close(FILE);
        print FIRSTLINE;
    }
    else {
        FIRSTLINE = "1970-01-01 00:00:00,000";
    }
 }
$0 ~ EXPRESSION {
    if (($2 " " $3) > FIRSTLINE) {
        print $0;
        LASTLINE=$2 " " $3;
    }
}
END {
    if (LASTLINE != "") {
        print LASTLINE > FILE;
    }
}
```

Any assistance with finding out why this is happening would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:

BASH Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
while getopts i:r:e:h:p: option
do
    case "${option}"
    in
        i) INPUT=${OPTARG};;
        r) RULES=${OPTARG};;
        e) PATFILE=${OPTARG};;
        h) HOST=${OPTARG};;
        p) PORT=${OPTARG};;
        ?) printf "Usage: %s: -i <\"file1.log file2.log\"> -r <\"rules1.awk rules2.awk\"> -e <\"patterns.pat\"> -h <host> -p <port>\n" $0;
           exit 1;
    esac
done

#prepare expression with sed
EXPRESSION=`cat $PATFILE | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/|/g'`;
EXPRESSION="^(INFO|DEBUG|WARNING|ERROR|FATAL)[[:space:]]{2}[[:digit:]]{4}\\\\-[[:digit:]]{1,2}\\\\-[[:digit:]]{1,2}[[:space:]][[:digit:]]{1,2}:[[:digit:]]{2}:[[:digit:]]{2},[[:digit:]]{3}.*"$EXPRESSION".*";

#Make sure the temp file is empty
echo "" > .temp;

#input through awk.
for file in $INPUT
do
    awk -v EXPRESSION="$EXPRESSION" -f $RULES $file >> .temp;
done

#send contents of file to splunk indexer over udp
cat .temp;
#cat .temp | netcat -t $HOST $PORT;

#cleanup temporary files
if [ -f .temp ]
then
    rm .temp;
fi
```

Patterns File (The stuff I want to match):

```
Warning
Exception
```

Awk script as above.

Example.log

```
info  2012-09-04 16:00:11,638 [[adr-com-adaptor-stub].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] nz.co.amsco.interop.multidriveinterop: session not initialised
error 2012-09-04 16:00:11,639 [[adr-com-adaptor-stub].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] nz.co.amsco.adrcomadaptor.processor.comadaptorprocessor: nz.co.amsco.interop.exceptions.systemdownexception
nz.co.amsco.interop.exceptions.systemdownexception
    at nz.co.amsco.adrcomadaptor.processor.comadaptorprocessor.getdeviceconfig(comadaptorprocessor.java:233)
    at nz.co.amsco.adrcomadaptor.processor.comadaptorprocessor.process(comadaptorprocessor.java:129)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.defaultmessageprocessorchain.doprocess(defaultmessageprocessorchain.java:99)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.abstractmessageprocessorchain.process(abstractmessageprocessorchain.java:66)
    at org.mule.processor.abstractinterceptingmessageprocessorbase.processnext(abstractinterceptingmessageprocessorbase.java:105)
    at org.mule.processor.asyncinterceptingmessageprocessor.process(asyncinterceptingmessageprocessor.java:90)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.defaultmessageprocessorchain.doprocess(defaultmessageprocessorchain.java:99)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.abstractmessageprocessorchain.process(abstractmessageprocessorchain.java:66)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.java:105)
    at org.mule.interceptor.AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.process(AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.java:55)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.java:105)
```

Usage:

> ./filter.sh -i "Example.log" -r "rules.awk" -e "patterns.pat" -h host -p port

Note that host and port are both unused in this version as the output is just thrown onto stdout.

So if I run this I get the following output:

> info  2012-09-04 16:00:11,638 [[adr-com-adaptor-stub].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] nz.co.amsco.interop.multidriveinterop: session not initialised
>   error 2012-09-04 16:00:11,639 [[adr-com-adaptor-stub].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] nz.co.amsco.adrcomadaptor.processor.comadaptorprocessor: nz.co.amsco.interop.exceptions.systemdownexception
>       at nz.co.amsco.adrcomadaptor.processor.comadaptorprocessor.getdeviceconfig(comadaptorprocessor.java:233)
>       at nz.co.amsco.adrcomadaptor.processor.comadaptorprocessor.process(comadaptorprocessor.java:129)

If I run it again on the same unchanged file I should get no output however I am seeing:

> nz.co.amsco.adrcomadaptor.processor.comadaptorprocessor.process(comadaptorprocessor.java:129)

I have been unable to determine why this is happening.

Comment: I spent about 10 minutes but I even can't reproduce your problem: script doesn't define `EXPRESSION`, when I defined it manually I see that this expression doesn't apply to provided input example. Please provide working example which allows to reproduce the problem (http://sscce.org).

Comment: Dunno. Would rather have zip somehow take care of data volume considerations. I have seen 800Mb becoming 6Mb. Also, I always happen to need to change the filters I am using. I would hate it if the data would be incomplete, because of some filter bug/requirement. Why not provide for convenient filter tools for the developers/QA/supporters instead?

Comment: I've added the extra scripts etc so now my problem should be completely reproducible. Apologies, I should have done that when I posted the question.

Comment: The information that is sent to the server is indexed by an existing product (Splunk) so I have no control over how that does compression etc internally. All I can do on my end to limit the amount of data that is indexed is by actually filtering what I send to Splunk.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't provide any sample input that could reproduce your problem so let's start by just cleaning up your script and go from there. Change it to this:

```
BEGIN{
  expression = "^(INFO|DEBUG|WARNING|ERROR|FATAL)[[:space:]]{2}[[:digit:]]{4}-[[:digit:]]{1,2}-[[:digit:]]{1,2}[[:space:]][[:digit:]]{1,2}:[[:digit:]]{2}:[[:digit:]]{2},[[:digit:]]{3}.*Exception|Warning"
    # Do you really want "(Exception|Warning)" in brackets instead?
    # As written "Warning" on its own will match the whole expression.
}

FNR == 1 {
    tstampFile = "/" FILENAME ".last"
    sub(/.*\//,".",tstampFile)

    if ( (getline prevTstamp < tstampFile) > 0 ) {
        close(tstampFile)
        print prevTstamp
    }
    else {
        prevTstamp = "1970-01-01 00:00:00,000"
    }

    nextTstamp = ""
}

$0 ~ expression {
    currTstamp = $2 " " $3
    if (currTstamp > prevTstamp) {
        print
        nextTstamp = currTstamp
    }
}

END {
    if (nextTstamp != "") {
        print nextTstamp > tstampFile
    }
}
```

Now, do you still have a problem? If so, show us how you run the script, i.e. the bash command you are executing, and post some small sample input that reproduces your problem.

Comment: I updated my question with all the supporting scripts etc to reproduce my problem. Hopefully there is enough information there now :)